# How to template a Page Directive in Razor

Tags: razormediator

I would like to assign the `UTF-8` as My page encoding for Arabic Language using the below code

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

But I got error message

Comment: Please clarify your question and add the code also. http://elenaserghie.blogspot.in/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html link can help you also

Comment: What's that error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the @ character is special in Razor, to output a literal @ you need to double it. So instead of

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

you must say:

```
<%@@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```